# How to add an icon on image after a click in jquery and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image. When i click on the image it changes the border and opacity. This is working. But how can i add an icon on this image after a click ?

my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ptud8knL/1/

I've tried to make position of the icon relative and then change the z-index but this is not working as i thought.

```js
$('img').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).css('opacity') == 1) {
    $(this).css({
      'opacity': '0.5',
      'border': '3px solid #5cb85c'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).css({
      'opacity': '1',
      'border': ''
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 0px solid #5cb85c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/82851ba7fe.js"></script>
<img id="eiffel" src="https://demo.cloudimg.io/width/200/s/http://sample.li/eiffel.jpg" alt="eiffel">
<i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5cb85c"></i>
```

Comment: What kind of icon are you talking about? Is that an image or fontawesome icon?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to place the `img` and the `i` within a containing `div`. You can then attach the click handler to that `div`, and toggle a class on it. You can then write the CSS rules based on that class to hide/show the icon, and set the styles on the `img`. Try this:

```js
$('.container').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container i {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 65px;
  color: #5cb85c;
}

.container.active img {
  border: 3px solid #5cb85c;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container.active i {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/82851ba7fe.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img id="eiffel" src="https://demo.cloudimg.io/width/200/s/http://sample.li/eiffel.jpg" alt="eiffel">
  <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Jquery, you can add class to your icon :

```
$('img').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).css('opacity') == 1) {
    $(this).css({'opacity':'0.5', 'border':'3px solid #5cb85c'});
  }
  else {
    $(this).css({'opacity':'1', 'border':''});
  } 
  $('i').addClass('icon');
});
```

And your css :

```
.active {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 0px solid #5cb85c;
}

.icon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  }
```

Change de css of `.icon` if you need to change the icon position.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
.fa-5x {
  position:relative;
  left:-75px;
  top:-10px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ptud8knL/6/)